# Split the prices from string and place it in another column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have below dataframe:

```
Charges:
Shipping:800.00
Processing:9000.00
Commission:150.00
```

What I'm trying to do is to split charge amounts separately to different column:

```
Charges:     Prices:
Shipping     800.00
Processing   9000.00
Commission   150.00
```

Tried to use regex and `df['Prices'] = df['Charges'].str.split('[0+9]', expand=True)` with no success.

Any suggestions:

Comment: I do not think regex is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `split`:

```py
splitted = df['Charges'].str.split(':', expand=True)
df['Charges'] = splitted[0]
df['Price'] = splitted[1]
```

Comment: Try this one-liner: `df['Charges:'].str.split(':', expand=True).set_axis(['Charges:', 'Prices'], axis=1)`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str.extract` here:

```py
df["Prices"] = df["Charges"].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+))')
df["Charges"] = df["Charges"].str.extract(r'^([^:]+)')
```